# Need to install laravel remotely and save to remote repository on bitbucket

Tags: laravel, git, bitbucket

I have created a repository on bitbucket. I am installing a laravel installation on my remote computer and I want to initialize git and connect it to the repository on bitbucket so I can share the project.

Once I have created the repository on bitbucket and setup ssh-agent, I am able to connect to it and clone the empty repository to my remote machine. So, I then go into my laravel directory, I type:

```
>> git init
>> git add --all
>> git commit -m "Laravel Install"
>> git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:acct_name/repository_name.git
```

And then finally:

```
>>git push -u origin master
```

The system gives me back this error message:

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know my ssh key is correct because I can clone that repository into a different directory using the command:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:acct_name/repository_name.git
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

In answer to the comment below. Testing the ssh connection produces:

```
>ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

Comment: what do you see get when your run `ssh -t git@bitbucket.org` ? Did you also check [Troubleshooting guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/testing-your-ssh-authentication-1167819709.html)